# Error when doing force alignment via HTK

Tags: ubuntu, speech, htk

I am going to do the force alignment and I follow the tutorial from the HTK book.

When I execute Hvite command to do force alignment,

```
HVite -a -b sil -m -o SWT -I config/monophn.mlf -H am/hmm5/newMacros config/dgs.dict config/monophn.list mfc/0_1.mfc
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR [+8220] LatticeFromLabels: word sil not defined in dictionary
FATAL ERROR - Terminating program Hvite
```

Anyone has faced this before?

I am working on Ubuntu 10.0.4, HTK3.4.1

Answer (score 1):

As message suggests, you need to add sil to the dictionary:

```
 sil sil
```

Or you need to remove `-b sil` from the command line if you don't want to have silence on boundaries.